# PHP add new rules default language in .htacces

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have two languages in my website (`en` & `fr`). I rewrite my url using `.htaccess` like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /pms/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(fr|en)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?.html$ article.php?page=$2&id=$3&title=$4&lang=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

This worked with my url for both language like this:

```
website.com/en/page/10/title.html   <- english language
website.com/fr/page/10/title.html   <- french language
```

My defualt language is `en` and I  need to remove the default language from url and show only second language in url like this:

```
website.com/page/10/title.html  <- english language
website.com/fr/page/10/title.html  <- french language
```

How do I create rules for this?

Comment: Can you not achieve this in PHP using a routing layer?

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /pms/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(fr)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?.html$ article.php?page=$2&id=$3&title=$4&lang=$1 [NC,L,QSA] 

#Rule for en
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?.html$ article.php?page=$1&id=$2&title=$3&lang=en [NC,L,QSA]
```